# Django-oscar "No module named sorl_kvstore"

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I added a product with image in the dashboard. But, every time I try to access it on the localhost it gives me the following error-

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /dashboard/catalogue/
Error importing module oscar.sorl_kvstore: "No module named sorl_kvstore"
```

On the following line -

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% if record.primary_image.original.url %}
    {% with image=record.primary_image %}


  --> {% thumbnail image.original "70x70" upscale=False as thumb %}
```

I have just started out with oscar and can't understand why this is happening. I followed the instructions to create my own shop and migrated settings from sandbox-settings.py.

Comment: This bug was resolved last year itself. Check [link](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/commit/674bd9ef84fa5fc8dffda93b0fb1258a06138e52). I think you'll have to update `django-oscar`. Also, you can refer [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-oscar/FOEAePMhq0Q/ZJeKJxIcpDQJ)

Comment: I have installed oscar today and have installed the latest version. And I also have the line included that is in the link.